# Why am I getting null value while using "sendReditect" in servlet as per below

Tags: java, servlets

Why am I getting null value while using "sendReditect" in servlet as per below

my code as per below : I am getting fname value null even in both FirstServlet and SecondServlet

**index.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="FirstServlet" method="get">
        username<input type="text" name="fname"></br> <input type="submit"
            value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**FirstServlet:**

```
    package com.naveen;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FirstServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/FirstServlet")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s3=request.getParameter("fname");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*String s1=request.getParameter("t1");*/
        /*RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("SecondServlet");
        rd.forward(request, response);*/
        res.sendRedirect("SecondServlet");
        System.out.println("your output as per" +s3);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**SecondServlet:**

```
package com.naveen;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SecondServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SecondServlet")
public class SecondServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String s3=request.getParameter("fname");

        out.print("hi i am siddharth");
        out.println(s3);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why i am getting null value while using "sendReditect" in servlet as
>   per below my code as per below : i am getting fname value null even in
>   both FirstServlet and SecondServlet,

Because you're not setting any values to your request. You need to set the value to the request like this:

```
@WebServlet("/FirstServlet")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s3=request.getParameter("fname"); //get the value you set in your jsp/html/url


        request.setAttribute("fname", s3); // set the s3 value to the request

        res.sendRedirect("SecondServlet");
        System.out.println("your output as per" +s3);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

I'm assuming here you have sent the fname value via a form or something. If you call `FirstServlet` by just typing it in the url, you will get null.

But not if you set something, try it like this if you are not submitting a form:

```
/FirstServlet?fname=helloworld
```

**EDIT:**

just noticed in your form you're not actually setting fname with any value. You need to give it a value:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="FirstServlet" method="get">
        username<input type="text" name="fname" value="helloworld"></br> //add value to your input!! 
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming here you have sent the fname value via a form or something. If you call FirstServlet by just typing it in the url, you will get null.                                                                                                                                   
*******************************************************************************                                                                                                         
 Sid--> in form tag action i called "FirstServlet", this is only standard procedure , why i will get null ?

Comment: Okay, check my edited answer... You are not giving fname a value attribute in the input of your form! Try my new answer

Comment: bro it;s not compulsory to be value with name , anyway it;s resolved after i restarted tomcat ..

Comment: anyway it;s resolved after restarting tomcat, the thing is that in the case sendRedirect the request will go from index to FirstServlet and it;s will print the values but suppose in FirstServlet you are doing sendRedirect to SecondServlet but now the request is not same in SecondServlet  as per FirstServlet , it;s means in the case of sendRedirect it will create new request in SecondServlet so it;s printing null values .